# React Native Navigation 5 import "Element type invalid"

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation-v5

After months without `react-native` I can solve some simple problems .
I'm import the navigation component and I always get:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `NavBottomBar`.
>
> This error is located at:
> in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:390)

Here the code:

```
import React from 'react';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

// SCREENS

import AddBook from '../screens/AddBook';
import BookArchive from '../screens/BookArchive';

// ICONS
import EvilIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/EvilIcons';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

const SearchIcon = () => {
  return <EvilIcons name="search" size={20} color="black" />;
};

const BookArchiveIcon = () => {
  return <Ionicons name="md-library-sharp" size={20} color="black" />;
};


const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const NavTab = () => {
return(
  <Tab.Navigation>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Add"
      component={AddBook}
      options={({route}) => ({
        tabBarColor: '#000',
        tabBarLabel: 'Add a Book',
        tabBarIcon: () => SearchIcon(),
      })}
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Libray"
      component={BookArchive}
      options={({route}) => ({
        tabBarColor: '#000',
        tabBarLabel: 'Library',
        tabBarIcon: () => BookArchiveIcon(),
      })}
    />
  </Tab.Navigation>
)
};

const NavBottomBar = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="My Book Store"
          component={NavTab}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default NavBottomBar;
```

Super simple. And here the import in `App.js`

```
... // various components
import NavBottomBar from './src/components/NavBottomBar';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <SafeAreaView>
          <NavBottomBar />
          <AddBook />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```

I tried everything but the solution!

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Tab.Navigator`, not `Tab.Navigation`.

Unrelated, but you should also render the icon as react element instead of calling them as functions.

```js
const NavTab = () => {
  return(
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Add"
        component={AddBook}
        options={({route}) => ({
          tabBarColor: '#000',
          tabBarLabel: 'Add a Book',
          tabBarIcon: () => <SearchIcon />,
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Libray"
        component={BookArchive}
        options={({route}) => ({
          tabBarColor: '#000',
          tabBarLabel: 'Library',
          tabBarIcon: () => <BookArchiveIcon />,
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
};
```

Using something like TypeScript would eliminate these kind of mistakes.

Comment: thanks but I already found it. Can you please explain how works / how to use typescript?

Answer (score 2):

It might be late but let me put my solution to a similar problem I experienced as it might help someone facing the same problem in the future. I had a tab navigator (`MaterialBottomTabNavigator`) inside `Stack Navigator`. The Problem was, unfortunately, I installed incompatible (different) versions of `react-navigation` and `material-bottom-tab-navigation`. I used `npm install @react-navigation/native` and `npm install @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs@next` which are from two different versions (as you can see the version of the `react-native/material-bottom-tabs` is `6.x(next)` while that of `react-navigation/native` is `5.x`). As a result I had to change `npm install @react-navigation/native` to `npm install @react-navigation/native@next`, which is the same version with `react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs`. The same is true for `react-navigation/stack` as well. You should use `npm install @react-navigation/stack@next` instead of `npm install @react-navigation/stack`.

**In short**: if you install version `5.x` of `react-navigation`, you should install version `5.x` of both `react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` and `react-navigation/stack`. The same is true for version `6.x(next)` too.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return component in NavTab

```
const NavTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigation>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Add"
        component={AddBook}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarColor: '#000',
          tabBarLabel: 'Add a Book',
          tabBarIcon: () => SearchIcon(),
        })}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Libray"
        component={BookArchive}
        options={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarColor: '#000',
          tabBarLabel: 'Library',
          tabBarIcon: () => BookArchiveIcon(),
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigation>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks! True. but this doens't change it! any other idea?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you run it again.

Comment: Can you show your code in BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:390

Comment: well is the standard for the navigation. is not mine